# How do I use a function depending on the type of an argument?

Tags: opengl, haskell

I am using Haskell and OpenGL. OpenGL has a way to load variables using a set of *uniform* functions:

```
glUniform1i location intValue
glUniform1f location floatValue
glUniform2i location intValue1 intValue2
... etc.
```

I am trying to translate this into more idiomatic Haskell. I would like to write a function:

```
uniform :: String -> a -> IO ()
uniform location value = ...
```

My problem is that the function I call is dependent on the value of `a`. Is there a way to do this without  writing **n** different functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to define such function is to define new [type class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types) like:

```
class GlUniformable a where
    uniform:: String -> a -> IO()
```

each instance could have definition like

```
instance GlUniformable Int where
    uniform location value = ...
```

where `value` will be understood as parameter of type `Int` by the compiler

Comment: Notice this is rather close to how the OpenGL Haskell bindings currently do it: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-2.9.1.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-Shaders-Uniform.html#v:uniform

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I've taken a look before at some of the C interface in that library but I didn't think to look for this. Thanks! EDIT: And thanks, Odomontois. I'm not sure if I will go this route since it's starting to deviate from standard OpenGL (too much?). But I will use the idea in other forms.